# How do I access a DB record's column that is stored in viewdata?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

The following code works just fine:
(In Controller [Visual Basic]):
            Dim DivUsers(16)

```
        For Each did In Divisions
            Dim perm = Perms(did)
            DivUsers(did) = From u In db.VEAUsers Where u.Permission = perm
        Next
```

(In View [HTML/RAZOR]):

```
@For Each u In ViewBag.DivUsers(did)
    @<option value="@u.UserId">@u.FirstName @u.LastName</option>
    cnt = cnt + 1
Next
```

However I am being asked to use ViewData instead of ViewBag (because of EXPLICIT/STRICT OPTIONs).

I am not sure how to access the individual records in ViewData much like I can when the records are in ViewBag.  That is, how do I rewrite this line of HTML/RAZOR code using ViewData instead of ViewBag?

```
                @For Each u In ViewBag.DivUsers(did)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

ViewData is a dictionary so is you want to put model to your `ViewData` in your controller you should write:

```
ViewData["Users"] = model;
```

and then on View you can get values like this:

```
@For Each u In ViewData["Users"].DivUsers(did)
    @<option value="@u.UserId">@u.FirstName @u.LastName</option>
    cnt = cnt + 1
Next
```

But the **best practice** is to use `ViewData.Model` and **Strongly Typed Views**.

```
ViewData.Model = model;
```

Then on View:

```
@For Each u In ViewData.Model.DivUsers(did)
    @<option value="@u.UserId">@u.FirstName @u.LastName</option>
    cnt = cnt + 1
Next
```

But you should specify model for your View on the top

```
@model YourModelClass
```

Comment: I am not sure I clearly understand this part:
    ViewData.Model = model;

And I am not sure that I can specify the model for the View (but I can certainly try.)